# get model items results as array in Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel-4

I want the output of a select to be returned as array but not an object.

I have tried these-

```
User::all()->toArray();//returns array but don't know how to add filters, as it will give all the rows from the 'users' table. what if I want some of them. how to do it?

User::select('id','>','5')->toArray(); //call to undefined method toArray()
```

What should I use then? Really confused!

One more thing, where are the working of these functions mentioned exactly in the docs? I found the API docs very confusing. They don't point directly to functions I think. Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me-

```
Thought::where('id','>',$last_message_id)->get()->toArray();
```

Closely observe the `toArray()` at the end.

Answer (score 1):

`get()` runs the query on the database and will return a [`Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection`](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html), which has the method [`toArray()`](http://laravel.com/api/4.1/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Collection.html#method_toArray). So you need to use this to get your array:

```
User::select('id','>','5')->get()->toArray();
```

But maybe you dont even need that array, the Collection class has some powerful methods you maybe could use instead.

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you also check out this original documentation

- http://laravel.com/docs/queries#selects

Dont you have to be using DB class instead of User::* in your code

Take a look at this example

```
$users = DB::table('users')
                ->where('votes', '>', 100)
                //->orWhere('name', 'John')
                ->get();
```

and

```
$users->toArray(); or 
$users->all()->toArray();
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you have to use method chaining and `where()` is you solution here.

```
User::where("item", "=", "value")->get();
```

Comment: this wont return an array

Comment: what it will return then, object and you want array?

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in question

Comment: have checked type-casting? `(array)$db_result;`

Comment: that's doesn't have to do anything here. I have answered the question

Comment: @user1708762 if you answered your question already, please accept the answer you used.

Comment: I can't do that till two days, its stackoverflow constraint.